# How to prove this in smart way

Tags: calculus

How to prove this in a a smart way?

> If $y= \sin (m  \sin^{-1} (x))$, then $(1-x^2)y^{(n+2)}-(2n+1)x{y^{(n+1)}}+(m^2-n^2)y^{(n)}=0$ derivative.

I have been able to prove it by differentiating it twice and using Leibniz theorem, but thats very long, is there a nice way to prove this?

Comment: You could use $y^{(n)}$ for $y_n$.

Answer (score 0):

$$y'=m(1-x^2)^{-1/2}\cos(m\sin^{-1}(x))$$
$$y''=mx(1-x^2)^{-3/2}\cos(m\sin^{-1}(x))-m^2(1-x^2)^{-1}\sin(m\sin^{-1}(x)),$$
so that $$(1-x^2)y''-xy'+m^2y=0.$$
this establishes the base case of the recurrence.

Now derive

$$(1-x^2)y^{(n+2)}-(2n+1)xy^{(n+1)}+(m^2-n^2)xy^{(n)}=0$$ and get

$$-2xy^{(n+2)}+(1-x^2)y^{(n+3)}-(2n+1)y^{(n+1)}-(2n+1)xy^{(n+2)}+(m^2-n^2)y^{(n+1)}=0,$$
or after regrouping (denoting $n^+:= n+1$)
$$(1-x^2)y^{(n^++2)}-(2n^++1)xy^{(n^++1)}+\left(m^2-(n^+)^2\right)y^{(n^+)}=0.$$

Comment: Thanks I want to apply the same technique  for $y=(x^2-1)^n$ to prove >$y^{(n+2)}-2xy^{(n+1)}+n(n+1)y^{(n)}=0$ but I am not able to prove the base case taking $n=0$

Comment: Do you mean $n$ or $m$ ?

Comment: I want to apply the same induction technique on a different problem.